# Silverstripe GridFieldOrderableRows issue: Uncaught Exception: Couldn't find the sort field 'Sort'

Tags: php, sorting, silverstripe

I'm trying to make sortable content on SilverStripe but I keep getting an error

> Uncaught Exception: Couldn't find the sort field 'Sort'

I am using gridfieldextension.
I have **AboutPage class**:

```
class AboutPage extends Page {
private static $db = array(
    'Text' => 'HTMLText',
    'AboutTitle' => 'Varchar(124)',
    'DiplomaTitle' => 'Varchar(124)'
);
private static $has_one = array(
    'Image' => 'Image',             'VideoFile' => 'File'
);
private static $has_many = array(
    'Diplomas' => 'Diploma'
);

public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = parent::getCMSFields();

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextField::create('AboutTitle', '"About me"'));
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', UploadField::create('Image', 'Image')->setFolderName('Uploads/About'));             $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', UploadField::create('VideoFile', 'Video')->setFolderName('Uploads/Home'));  
    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', HtmlEditorField::create('Text', 'Text'));

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', TextField::create('DiplomaTitle', '"Diplomai" pavadinimas'));
    $configDiploma = GridFieldConfig_RecordEditor::create();
    $configDiploma->addComponent(new GridFieldOrderableRows());
    $gridDiploma = new GridField('Diplomas', 'Diplomas', $this->Diplomas(), $configDiploma);

    $fields->addFieldToTab('Root.Main', $gridDiploma);

    $fields->removeByName('Content');

    return $fields;
}
```

and this is my **Diploma class**:

```
class Diploma extends DataObject {
private static $default_sort = 'Sort ASC';
private static $db = array(
    'Sort' => 'Int'
);
private static $has_one = array(
    'Image' => 'Image',
    'AboutPage' => 'AboutPage'
);
private static $summary_fields = array(
    'Image.StripThumbnail'
);

public function getCMSFields() {
    $fields = FieldList::create(
        UploadField::create('Image', 'Image')->setFolderName('Uploads/Diplomas')
    );

    return $fields;
}
```

About page works fine, but the admin page to edit stops working as soon as I add the `$configDiploma->addComponent(new GridFieldOrderableRows())` . I saw some topics about Parent/Children relations, but even if I make the workarounds like here: [SilverStripe gridfield multi class editor has invalid sort() column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33075844/silverstripe-gridfield-multi-class-editor-has-invalid-sort-column) and add the code in an if 
it still throws the same error. Am I missing something ?

Function in GridFieldOrderableRows.php that throws an error:

```
    public function getSortTable(DataList $list) {
    $field = $this->getSortField();

    if($list instanceof ManyManyList) {
        $extra = $list->getExtraFields();
        $table = $list->getJoinTable();

        if($extra && array_key_exists($field, $extra)) {
            return $table;
        }
    }

    $classes = ClassInfo::dataClassesFor($list->dataClass());

    foreach($classes as $class) {
        if(singleton($class)->hasOwnTableDatabaseField($field)) {
            return $class;
        }
    }

    throw new Exception("Couldn't find the sort field '$field'");
}
```

Comment: Have you done a `dev/build?flush=all` It sounds like the Sort field doesn't exist in the Diploma table.

Comment: yeah, it seems that it was cached somehow and couldn't find the Sort table. Thank You, Gavin ! Could You write an answer to accept it as a correct one ?:)